# Vue.js - Write JSON object to local file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

Some while ago I started learning Vue.js and a short while after, I started a bigger project, not keeping in mind, that Javascript has limited options to interact with the local file system.
I set up the project via vue-cli, so I have to start the website via `npm start`.

Said project consist of a visual editor for JSON Files. When I wanted to implement the save button, I recognized that it's a quite difficult task to make is write/save (and maybe read in the future) a JSON file to my local machine.

I already tried using node's `fs` library, thinking it would work, because it is launched with node.
I also tried several external libraries e.g. the `write-json-file` npm lib.

I'm getting to a point where I'm out of ideas and would do pretty much anything thats necessary to make it work.

Comment: Well to interact with the file system you most likely would need some node server. Like using express or some kind of webserver, with which you could then communicate from your vue.js webapp

Comment: Are you going to use server side or client side generate json and write to local?

Comment: The json data will be created "live" and stored in a vuex store. There will never be a "real" server side, for this should be like a windows application and never be accessed via the internet. I know it's quite odd to use javascript for something like this, but the specifications for this were a webbased project.

Comment: I think if using browser env you can only either create a blob to download or write to local storage or IndexDB. I can share you a example I have done if it will help. But as your description you wanna implement something like VSCode or Atom. For your usecase, you can try to look at Electron

Comment: A download button seems like a feasible option, if its not that complicated :)
I know that there are alternatives, but it's more of an educational project in the scope of my university than a real life usecase. An example would be nice

Comment: Ok, I can submit a sample on how to create blob and also how to write into localstorage I have tried before

Comment: I already found out how to write into the local storage, that is my primary form of persisting data at the moment. But I'd appreciate the blob one.

Comment: Posted as below. If any problem feel free to let me know

Comment: I didn't expect to get an answer this fast, I'll try it out tomorrow. Many thanks anyways, it looks like this could be the long sought after solution :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do this.

1. Write to local storage
2. Create a Blob and invoke an event to download it
3. Wrap it into a electron app and use node `fs` module to save file

I can show you a sample here for these 3 cases

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vue-app">
    <form>
        <input type="text" v-model="name"/>{{name}}<br/>
        <input type="text" v-model="last"/>{{last}}<br/>
        <input type="text" v-model="index"/>{{index}}<br/>
        <select v-model="grade">
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
        </select>
        {{grade}}
        <button type="button" v-on:click="add()">Add To Table</button>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="saveFile()">saveFile</button>
    </form>
    <table border="1">
        <thead><td>Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Index</td><td>Grade</td></thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="x in arr">
            <td>{{x.first}}</td>
            <td>{{x.lastn}}</td>
            <td>{{x.index}}</td>
            <td>{{x.grade}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js (**Write to local storage**)

```
new Vue ({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
      name: '',
      last: '',
      index: 0,
      grade: 0,
      arr: []
  },

  methods: {
      add: function (e) {
          this.arr.push({first: this.name, lastn: this.last, index: this.index, grade: this.grade});
          console.log(1);
      },
      saveFile: function() {
        const data = JSON.stringify(this.arr)
        window.localStorage.setItem('arr', data);
        console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('arr')))
  }
});
```

**Create a Blob and invoke a event to download it**

only change for saveFile func

```
saveFile: function() {
    const data = JSON.stringify(this.arr)
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'})
    const e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = "test.json";
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
    e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

**Wrap it into an Electron app and use node `fs` module to save file**

Change for saveFile func

```
saveFile: function() {
    const data = JSON.stringify(this.arr)
    const fs = require('fs');
    try { fs.writeFileSync('myfile.txt', data, 'utf-8'); }
    catch(e) { alert('Failed to save the file !'); }
}
```

Then use [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) to wrap it

`electron ./index.html`

Comment: Glad that I can help you. If possible just accept my answer

Comment: Maybe pedantic, but why go through all the trouble of creating a link element and then triggering a click on it, when it's just as easy to trigger the download without it. Solution seems really fragile.

Comment: @Hybridwebdev You can also use this lib  to save the file. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/edit/master/src/FileSaver.js. It is using a.href and click event as well.  Or you can use the download API but it is not supported by Edge https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download

Comment: could you please explain how to wrap with electron?
i have no idea about electron.
i want to write a crud code generator for vue js like yii2 gii but i have no idea to create a directory or generate files to local project with vue and js

Comment: Making an electron app for the sole purpose of allowing the user to download something seems like serious overkill to me.

Comment: @Grumbunks Agreed. Sometimes product team needs to accept the limitation of certain tech and design a better alternative for it

Answer (score 1):

This is how I edit JSON files in my Vue projects. In this case, if you run the file, it will create a new data.json file and add Price to each  JSON object:

```
const fs = require("fs");

let cars = [
  {
    Name: "chevrolet chevelle malibu",
    Miles_per_Gallon: 18,
    Cylinders: 8,
    Displacement: 307,
    Horsepower: 130,
    Weight_in_lbs: 3504,
    Acceleration: 12,
    Year: "1970-01-01",
    Origin: "USA"
  },
  {
    Name: "buick skylark 320",
    Miles_per_Gallon: 15,
    Cylinders: 8,
    Displacement: 350,
    Horsepower: 165,
    Weight_in_lbs: 3693,
    Acceleration: 11.5,
    Year: "1970-01-01",
    Origin: "USA"
  }
];
cars.forEach(car => {
  car.price = 12000;
});

let data = JSON.stringify(cars);
fs.writeFileSync("data.json", data);
```

Comment: I get the error ``fs.writeFileSync is not a function``.