# File System to manage local folders and files of users

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, filesystems, mean-stack

I have a website built by mean-stack. I use [File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to create folders and write files in servers. For example, in the backend, i have:

```
router.post('/httpOnly/mkdir', function (req, res, next) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var dir = req.body.dir;
    fs.mkdir(dir, 0777, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === "EEXIST") console.log("folder exists")
            else return console.log(err)
        };
        res.json(dir);
    });
});
```

Now, I want to create folders in **local disks of users**. For example, when I launch the website in `localhost` (of Mac), i want it to be able to create a folder in my Mac. I tried to following code in the front-end:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('fileSystem', {
            url: '/fileSystem',
            template: `hallo`,
            controller: 'FileSystemCtrl'
        })
}])

app.controller('FileSystemCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    // var dir = "public/tmp/ABC" // creates well a folder under the folder of the project
    var dir = "file:///USers/SoftTimur/theProject/public/tmp/DEF"
    $http.post('/httpOnly/mkdir', { dir: dir })
        .then(function () {
            console.log("done")
        })
}])
```

I would hope, with `var dir = "file:///USers/SoftTimur/theProject/public/tmp/DEF"`, a folder could be created in my Mac, but it failed with an error:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'file:///USers/SoftTimur/theProject/public/tmp/DEF'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: 'file:///USers/SoftTimur/theProject/public/tmp/DEF' }
```

Does anyone how to do so?

Comment: Now imagine a malicious website doing this. Do you think it should be possible?

Comment: Isn't there no way to ask the permission from the user?

Comment: You need to use nested mkdir method and with the permission of user

Comment: @yueyou could you please give some details?

Comment: Posted an answer using sudo shell library. Feel free to let me know if there is any issues

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. Posted json data is

> { "dir": "/USers/softTimur/theProject/public/tmp/DEF"}

I am using sudo command `mkdir -p dirname` with password prompt with this library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser')
var sudo = require('sudo');
var options = {
    cachePassword: true,
    prompt: 'Password, yo? '
};

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  var fs = require('fs');
  var dir = req.body.dir;
  console.log(dir)
  var child = sudo([ 'mkdir', '-p', dir ], options);
  console.log(child.spawnargs)
  // var child = sudo([ 'ls', '-l'], options)
  child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data.toString());
      res.send(data.toString())
  });
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Comment: Another question is, this is really powerful, how could I prevent a website with this from running on my machine?

Comment: Thank you... it did create a folder, and printed the information in the backend console. But my `.then(function () { console.log("done") })` in the frontend was not executed (whereas with `ls -l` this is executed), do you know why?

Comment: This code is running in server side. So you don't need to worry about client side will create a folder like this way otherwise it is a kind of virus.

Comment: Do you mean the folder is always created in my server? Then, it is not what I want, I want to create folders in users' local disk...

Comment: If you intention is creating folder from client side. It seems not possible to create a folder under /User because of browser sandbox limitation. I have another answer for your intention. Check whether it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611671/vue-js-write-json-object-to-local-file/48612128#48612128

Comment: I don't mind whether the folders are created **from** client side or server side; I want to create folders and write files and modify files in the local disk **of** users (ie, visitors of my website). I have read your another answer: 1) `localStorage` can save string, but I do want to have files and folders; 2) for Blob and Electron, it seems that once the files are created, we cannot modify them easily in local disk of users.

Comment: Yes. It is clear that you want to manage folder and file in client(user) side like VSCode. I think it is not available for current browser eco. But you can consider a electron-based solution which will provide you the native OS api to manage folder in user side

Comment: I don't know much about Electron, it seems that it is used to build desktop applications. My website has already been built, and it will always run in browsers. In this case, do you think Electron could help?

Comment: Yes. I think it will help. Electron helps to convert your existing web app into a desktop app without much effort. But you may need to rethink about your product strategy based on the environment limitation