# fs.writeFile not working in newly created vue project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, fs

I have created a new Vue project using vue cli. Now when i added File write code in main.js, its giving error.

Code:

```
const fs = require('fs') ;
  
// Data which will write in a file. 
let data = "Learning how to write in a file.";
  
// Write data in 'Output.txt' . 
fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data, (err) => { 
      
    // In case of a error throw err. 
    if (err) throw err; 
}) ;
```

Error:
Uncaught TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function
at eval (main.js?56d7:20)
at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1217)
at **webpack_require** (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at Object.1 (app.js:1278)
at **webpack_require** (app.js:854)
at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
at app.js:994
at app.js:997

Comment: so you try to use the filesystem `fs` in a browser? witch is by the way not possible and only available in nodejs

Comment: i have written in js file. is there any way we can write file from Javascript?

Comment: in the browser, no

Comment: You can prompt the used to download the file though, you can find more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611671/vue-js-write-json-object-to-local-file/48612128).

Comment: thx a lot for reply.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know that `require` is used in node.js and not in the browser.
In the browser we use `import ... from ...`

Also, a browser has no access to the fileSystem. Thats what `fs` mean.

The browser is a sandbox. You cannot read / write to the fileSystem of your computer this privilege has a server.

Having access to the filesystem is a huge vulnerability